# Empty browser window when running a Shiny app with browser option

Tags: r, google-chrome, shiny

On some machines, I am having difficulty getting my Shiny app to open after specifying exactly where Chrome is and launching it like this:

```
chrome <- "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
options(browser = chrome)
shiny::runApp("./", launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Instead of displaying my Shiny app in my browser, I get this:

[image: screenshot]

utils::sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 15063)
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine for me, Try adding `(x86)`

```
chrome <- "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
options(browser = chrome)
shiny::runApp("C:/Users/me/Desktop/ShinyApp/ShinyApp", launch.browser = T)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to vote this down because the `(x86)` typo was my fault. ;)

Comment: It works fine on most machines, but the one above is giving me trouble